# Ler arquivo txt sempre que houver alterações

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

Estou com um problema em um projeto que estou realizando, preciso fazer um programa que leia um arquivo txt e importe para o MySQL, consegui fazer até essa parte. Porém agora preciso que esse programa fique lendo esse arquivo txt sempre que houver mudanças. E que importe para o MySQL apenas os novos dados cadastrados. Alguém poderia me ajuda? Dando algumas dicas de estudos. Ou algum exemplo. Estou começando agora em java. 
Obrigado.

```
package teste;

import java.io.*;   
import java.sql.*;   
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

class Teste{   
   public static void main(String args[]) {   
      try {   
         Class.forName("org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver");   
         Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Radius","root","admin");   
         Statement stm = con.createStatement();   
         BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("c:\\Users\\solutel\\Documents\\tabela\\tabela.txt"));

         String dados[] = new String[3];         
         String linha = reader.readLine();   
         while (linha != null) {   
            StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(linha,";\"");   
            dados[0] = st.nextToken();   
            dados[1] = st.nextToken();   

            stm.executeUpdate("insert into radcheck (username,attribute,op,value) values ('"+dados[0]+"','" +"User-Password"+ "','"+ ":="+ "','"+dados[1]+"')");   
            linha = reader.readLine();         
         }   
      }   
      catch (Exception e) {   
         System.err.println("Erro: " + e.getMessage());   
      }   
   }   
}
```

Comment: Poderia mostrar o que você já fez para assim receber ajuda.

Comment: Publiquei no tópico abaixo o programa.

Comment: Como assim? Você deve colocar na sua pergunta, e não como resposta. Você criou uma resposta e não um tópico.

Comment: Desculpe, é que sou novo no fórum. Tentei copiar por aqui porém deu comprimento excedido.

Comment: Tudo bem, você se acostuma. Aqui não é um Fórum, é um site de perguntas e respostas.

Comment: Ok. Você consegui me ajudar?

Comment: você pode criar uma função que lê o arquivo de tempo em tempos, se o arquivo tiver um tamanho diferente do anterior, então execute a importação.

Comment: Pesquise pela classe Observer e seu uso, no seu caso, ela poderá ajudar a fazer esse monitoramento de forma automática.

Answer (score 1):

Dei uma buscada rápida e encontrei essa biblioteca que talvez possa ser util para o que você precisa: [Jnotify](http://jnotify.sourceforge.net)

***EDIT:***

Me interessei por ser algo que eu pudesse utilizar no futuro tanto java puro como java/android mesmo...

Então fiz alguns testes e colocarei aqui todos os passo que fiz utilizando o [Jnotify](http://jnotify.sourceforge.net) para monitorar uma pasta ou arquivo, **Criado**, **Modificado**, **Deletado** ou **Renomeado**

**Configurando**

Extraia do arquivo `.zip` o arquivo `.jar` e o arquivo com o nome `jnotify.dll` para sistemas **32 bits** e `jnotify_64bit.dll` para sistemas **64 bits**

**NO ECLIPSE** - Depois de criar o projeto adicione a biblioteca **jar** ao projeto [exemplo aqui](http://pt.wikihow.com/Adicionar-JARs-nos-Caminhos-de-Acesso-de-Projeto-em-Eclipse-(Java)), em seguida adicionar a **dll** seguindo estes passos:

1. Criar uma pasta no projeto com nome `dll`
2. Colocar o arquivo .dll lá dentro
3. No projeto -> propriedades -> Java Build Path -> aba: Source clica no seuprojeto/src e expande
4. Clica em Native library location e em seguida no botão EDIT ao lado
5. Clica no botão Workspace e seleciona a pasta `dll` criada no primeiro passo.

**NO NETBEANS** - Adicionar o **.jar** ao projeto como explica [nesse link](http://www.guj.com.br/t/adcionar-jar-ao-projeto-netbeans/267873), e para a parte da **dll** eu encontrei os seguintes passos:

1. Acessar as propriedades do projeto
2. Clicar em RUN
3. Em VM Options, arrume: -Djava.library.path="C:\Diretório de onde está a DLL"

**Código**

Essa parte não tem mistério, eu criei uma classe apenas com o método `main` e o que precisava como ja mostra nos exemplos do próprio site do [JNotify](http://jnotify.sourceforge.net).

```
import net.contentobjects.jnotify.JNotify;
import net.contentobjects.jnotify.JNotifyListener;

public class Main {

      public static void main(String[] args) {

            try {
                  observarPasta();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
            }
      }

      public static void observarPasta() throws Exception {

          // criei uma pasta temp para observar os arquivos que forem
          // criados e alterados dentro dela, mas pode ser alterado
          // para um arquivo especifico

          String path = "C:\\temp";

          // a mask é as ações que vão ser observadas, mas pode
          // ser utilizado JNotify.FILE_ANY para monitorar tudo
          // também.

          int mask = JNotify.FILE_CREATED  |
                     JNotify.FILE_DELETED  |
                     JNotify.FILE_MODIFIED |
                     JNotify.FILE_RENAMED;

          // monitorar subPastas?
          boolean watchSubtree = true;

          // adiciona o "MONITORADOR"
          int watchID = JNotify.addWatch(path, mask, watchSubtree, new Listener());

          //Fica esperando um tempo até terminar a aplicação
          //Dependendo da implementação da sua aplicação
          //isso não será necessário mas para esse teste é interessante
          Thread.sleep(1000000);

          // aqui remove o seu "MONITORADOR"
          boolean res = JNotify.removeWatch(watchID);

          if (!res) {
            // o id foi inválido.
          }
        }

          //essa implementação ja se explica com seus métodos
        static class Listener implements JNotifyListener {
          public void fileRenamed(int wd, String rootPath, String oldName, String newName) {
            print("renomeado " + rootPath + " : " + oldName + " -> " + newName);
          }

          public void fileModified(int wd, String rootPath, String name) {
            print("modificado " + rootPath + " : " + name);
          }

          public void fileDeleted(int wd, String rootPath, String name) {

            print("deletado " + rootPath + " : " + name);
          }

          public void fileCreated(int wd, String rootPath, String name) {

            print("criado " + rootPath + " : " + name);
          }

          void print(String msg) {
            System.err.println(msg);
          }
        }
}
```

Comment: Boa tarde Furflez, consegui deixar em tempo real conforme seu código, porém quando altero o arquivo txt adicionando mais um dado. O programa insere os dados repetidos no Mysql e mais o adicionado. Pode me ajudar a inserir apenas o dado adicionado. Muito obrigado.

Comment: Bom, eu olhei o que pode ter sido, e encontrei em uma resposta do stackoverflowEN o mesmo problema, e isso pode ser devido ao sistema operacional... tenho duas sugestões mas dependem da forma de como você trabalha dentro desses arquivos. você poderia ao invés de pegar o evento de modificação, apagar o arquivo assim que lê e esperar pela criação de um novo no método `fileCreated`... ou manter em uma variável os últimos dados para comparação se aquele ja foi "trabalhado" como por exemplo um índice da linha, numero de caracteres... Acredito que isso possa te ajudar...